# facing problem in importing mxml file in action script using flex builder plugin in eclipse

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I am trying to create a flex app but facing a weird problem I have created a package to keep my mxml file separately and action script file separately. But the problem I am facing is when I am trying to import one of the .mxml component in my actionscript of main file of mxml application then I am not able to do so .can some one help me in importing one mxml file into other mxml file. my flash builder is not recognizing the package in which i have kept my other mxmk file

Comment: Are they in the same project?

Comment: thanks RIAstar I figured out my problem and learned that we cant import mxml file we can include mxml file in namespace and can only import actionscript file.

Comment: @Anupam Gupta If you found your answer, please write it up, post it as an answer to the question, and select it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem and learned that we cant import mxml file we can include mxml file in namespace and can only import actionscript file.